# How to scan IP address for hardware information?

Tags: memory, ip, hardware, cpu

If I have an IP address on my local network, is there a linux command or utility to scan it to reveal information about its processors and memory?

Comment: you'll have to execute a command on the machine with that ip to get this info (eg.. lshw)

Comment: Hmm are there any information gathering tools like things that might be included in Kali linux which might give hints to this information?

Comment: Without hacking `nmap` is probably your best bet. `nmap -A -T4 ${IPADDR}`. If you run this as root it can give you a MAC address and other useful information but not CPU/Memory

Comment: Some _services_ that may be running on the target machine might reveal this information, but notwithstanding that, no, a TCP/IP host is a TCP/IP host is a TCP/IP host.  You could probably infer the manufacturer of the hardware from the MAC address if you're close enough for the device to show on your ARP table, but that's about it.

Comment: `ipmitool` may help here - pass it the IP address of the server and query it remotely, man page at https://linux.die.net/man/1/ipmitool

Comment: @DopeGothi your comment would be worth a more detailed answer with information and examples on how to use this tool.

Comment: @steve your comment would be worth a more detailed answer with information and examples on how to use this tool.